# Uploading facebook url photo in CodegIgniter PHP

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I made a website that can log in with Facebook Account.

I could put basic user information easily but photo was not work at all.

here is my code for uploading photo.

```
$imageURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large';

$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$this->config->item('cf_dir_uphoto_temp');
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg';
$config['file_name'] = $this->session->userdata(SESSION_USERID).time();
$config['max_filename'] = '70';
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if($this->upload->do_upload('photo'))
{
$data = $this->upload->data();

$src_width = $src_height = ($data['image_width'] <= $data['image_height'])? $data['image_width'] : $data['image_height'];
$buffer_width = $buffer_height = 150;

$buffer_x = 0;
$buffer_y = 0;

$src_x = sprintf('%d', ($data['image_width'] - $src_width)/2);
$src_y = sprintf('%d', ($data['image_height'] - $src_height)/2);

$save_cropfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$this->config->item('cf_dir_uphoto_original').$data['file_name'];
$quality = 100;

if($data['file_type'] == 'image/jpeg')
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($data['full_path']);
    $buffer_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($buffer_width, $buffer_height);

    imagecopyresampled($buffer_img, $src_img,
                       $buffer_x, $buffer_y, $src_x, $src_y,
                       $buffer_width, $buffer_height, $src_width, $src_height
    );

    imagejpeg($buffer_img, $save_cropfile, $quality);
}else if($data['file_type'] == 'image/gif')
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($data['full_path']);
    $buffer_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($buffer_width, $buffer_height);

    imagecopyresampled($buffer_img, $src_img,
                       $buffer_x, $buffer_y, $src_x, $src_y,
                       $buffer_width, $buffer_height, $src_width, $src_height
    );

    imagegif($buffer_img, $save_cropfile);
}else if($data['file_type'] == 'image/png')
{
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($data['full_path']);
    $buffer_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($buffer_width, $buffer_height);

    imagecopyresampled($buffer_img, $src_img,
                       $buffer_x, $buffer_y, $src_x, $src_y,
                       $buffer_width, $buffer_height, $src_width, $src_height
    );
    imagepng($buffer_img, $save_cropfile);
}

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $save_cropfile;
$config['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$this->config->item('cf_dir_uphoto_thumb');
$config['width'] = 50;
$config['height'] = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->resize();

unlink($data['full_path']);

$p_data = $this->user->set_user_photo($data['file_name']);


}else
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

It's very wrong code.

$imageURL is the image address that will be converted to jpg address.

Can you give me an idea how to make this happen? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way of going about doing Facebook Login. If you want to show the user's photo in your app, you should use the API, instead of downloading the user's photo to your server. Just do something simple like:

`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_id}/picture?type=large" alt="{$username}" />`

This will let you use the image straight from Facebook, and it will automatically update when the user changes their profile picture. Your code would not update the user's picture if the user updated their profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to download the facebook users profile photo try this code , but first create a folder called image and make sure it has write permission enabled .

```
<?php

$fullpath = 'image/image.jpg';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$user_id}/picture?type=large";

function save_image($img, $fullpath) {
    $rawdata = file_get_contents($img);
    $fp = fopen($fullpath, 'w+');
    chmod($fullpath, 0777);
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
}



$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

if (isset($headers['Location'])) {
$url1 = $headers['Location']; // string
} else {
$url1 = false; // nothing there? .. weird, but okay!
}
save_image($url1, $fullpath);
?>
```